# How to re-create pg_stats_database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

We recently upgraded Postgres from v10 to v12.  The pg_stats_database listed a "datname" column with a null value.  Foolishly I deleted the view hoping to re-create it.

When trying to recreate the view I get a "system catalog modifications are currently not allowed" error.  I'm wary now of doing more harm that good.

1. What is the best method or re-creating the "pg_stats_database" view?
2. What may be causing a "null" datname to appear in that view?  Surely all databases need a name?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best method or re-creating the "pg_stats_database" view?

Set [allow_system_table_mods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-developer.html) to `on` in `postgresql.conf` and restart the instance.
Create the view in the `pg_catalog` schema, then switch the parameter to its default `off` for safety and restart again.

> What may be causing a "null" datname to appear in that view? Surely
>   all databases need a name?

Starting with PostgreSQL 12, this view has a row with `datid=0` and a null datname for objects shared across databases. See [`pg_stat_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW) in the v12 docs.